# Printing value of form input to console

Tags: javascript, forms, event-handling, submit, addeventlistener

can anyone tell why I am receiving this error?

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

I am trying to enter a value into a form, click submit, and print the value on the console.

Thanks :)

```
var form = document.querySelector('form.doing');
var input = form.addEventListener('submit', function(){
      console.log(input.value);
   });
```

This is a list app.

```
<form class="doing" method="post">
<input type="text" id="name" name="user_name" 
  placeholder="What needs doing?">
<button type="submit">Enter</button>
```

Comment: use window.onload() or $(function(){})

Comment: Using JQuery you can do $('form.doing'').serialize();